# Ошибка при компиляции с модулем Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, атрибуты, nuitka

При компиляции файла питон выходит такая ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\nuitka", line 78, in <module>
    from nuitka import MainControl, SyntaxErrors
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\MainControl.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .tree import (
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\tree\Recursion.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import Building
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\tree\Building.py", line 49, in <module>
    from nuitka.nodes.VariableRefNodes import (
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\nodes\VariableRefNodes.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .NodeBases import (
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\nodes\NodeBases.py", line 26, in <module>
    from nuitka.oset import OrderedSet
  File "C:\Users\help\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nuitka\oset.py", line 37, in <module>
    class OrderedSet( collections.MutableSet ):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSet'
```

Comment: https://github.com/Bogdanp/dramatiq/issues/428

Comment: @strawdog я прочитал, попытался исправить ничего не изменилось. Покажите, что именно нужно сделать.

Comment: и если ты не заметил, то это nuitka, @strawdog

Comment: Обновите nuitka до актуальной версии. Сейчас в исходниках вообще нет модуля nuitka\oset.py: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/tree/develop/nuitka